# How do you say, "I need to download an app", such as an iPhone app?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

My best guess comes from Google Translate.

> J’ai besoin de télécharger une application.

But how would a native French speaker say this? I'm not sure whether *télécharger* and *l'application* are the right choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*J’ai besoin de télécharger une application* is a correct translation and will fit most uses. As for many other technical terms, English words are often used in everyday language, especially among younger speakers, so you may also hear *J’ai besoin de downloader une application* or, even more colloquial, *J’ai besoin de downloader une app*, but beware that some people may frown upon using such *anglicismes*. You can also find the familiar apocope *appli* for *application*.

Comment: We could also minimize it even more with _J'ai besoin de dl une app_, but it is with people aware of its signification.

Comment: Or worse (or better?), in "text message French": *g besoin de dl 1 app*

Comment: Non, personne ne dit "downloader" en français.

Comment: Je persiste: *downloader* existe bel et bien en français courant. Sans doute pas à l'Académie française, mais c'est un anglicisme qu'on peut entendre et lire couramment, il suffit de chercher "comment downloader" sur Google, et des milliers de résultats seront retournés. Le mot est aussi est attesté sur Wiktionary, et de nombreux sites d'aide à la conjugaison en donnent les conjugaisons à tous les temps et modes. Cf. [http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/downloader.php]

Comment: (lien mal copié ci-dessus: http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/downloader.php )